# How to make AMP HTML cookies UUID version 4 compliant

Tags: cookies, uuid, amp-html, amp-analytics

One can set a custom key name for a AMP HTML cookie by passing it as the first argument to the [Client ID](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#client-id) analytics variable as in `${clientId(my-custom-cookie)}`, where `my-custom-cookie` is the desired cookie name.

The value of the custom AMP HTML cookie above may be a random base64 encoded string preceded with a `amp-` prefix as in `amp-V0pvjhu7pzZdRKQfDM-QYA`.

How can I effectively change the format of the cookie value in order to make it [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122) version 4 compliant?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a design goal of `<amp-analytics>` that developers not be able to change the format or entropy of the value of that cookie. I learned of this design goal when reading through their GitHub issues where developers were asking for new tracking options. The AMP developers expressed concern about too much entropy (https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/29324):

> Another question: Does a lower entropy session id work here? (e.g. 0-10000)

The CLIENT_ID becomes the value of that cookie, and its format and entropy are decided by the AMP framework (see https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/configure-analytics/analytics_basics/?format=websites#user-identification). The framework does allow changing the name of the cookie, as you noticed, which is helpful for integrations. A canonical page using custom JS can look for the cookie and see the value that AMP had set.